# cURL and json data convert into array and get only temp data

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I am new using json data. I am trying to call an api using cURL and converting it into array. I just want the temp data using foreach loop. But i am getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error. My code

```
$cSession = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=dhaka%2Cbangladesh&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=3");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$result = curl_exec($cSession);

curl_close($cSession);

//echo $result;
//$i = 3 as i am requesting 3 day data
for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) { 
  foreach ($result as $value) {
    echo $value['temp'][0]['day'];
    echo $value['temp'][0]['min'];

    echo $value['temp'][0]['max'];
    echo $value['temp'][0]['night'];
    echo $value['temp'][0]['eve'];
    echo $value['temp'][0]['morn'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$json = json_decode($result);
$res = $json->{'list'};
foreach ($res as $value) {
    echo $value->{'temp'}->{'day'} . "<br>";
    echo $value->{'temp'}->{'min'} . "<br>";
    echo $value->{'temp'}->{'max'} . "<br>";
    echo $value->{'temp'}->{'night'} . "<br>";
    echo $value->{'temp'}->{'eve'} . "<br>";
    echo $value->{'temp'}->{'morn'} . "<br>";
}
```

In your query string you have the value `metric&cnt=3` this is what you want for days to be extracted if you get from `cnt=10` you will have 10 results. No need for a `for` loop.

Comment: thanks a lot alex :) 
Stucked here for almost an hour

Answer (score 1):

the result is JSON that you should parse with `json_decode` first

edit with more code:

```
...
$result = json_decode($result,true);
for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) {
foreach ($result['list'] as $value) {
    echo $value['temp']['day'];
    echo $value['temp']['min'];
...
```

Comment: added some code that fixes the array reference issues as well

Answer (score 1):

With the `curl_exec` you'll get a json as a string, you have to parse it first to use it.
Try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

And don't forget to set the second parameter to true if you want the result as an array.

Comment: adding true as second parameter json data becomes multidimentional array. Already tried with that

Comment: Yes and then you could iterate through it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

curl_exec with the option CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to true will return the result of fetch the url you have set so your variable $result is a STRING.

You hace to convert to an array:

```
$cSession = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=dhaka%2Cbangladesh&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=3");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$result = curl_exec($cSession);

curl_close($cSession);
$result = json_decode($result,true);
//echo $result;
//$i = 3 as i am requesting 3 day data
for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) { 
  foreach ($result as $value) {
    echo $value['temp'][0]['day'];
    echo $value['temp'][0]['min'];

    echo $value['temp'][0]['max'];
    echo $value['temp'][0]['night'];
    echo $value['temp'][0]['eve'];
    echo $value['temp'][0]['morn'];
  }
}
```

Comment: converting json_decode() getting an error illigal string object

Comment: Confirm that your result is a json string before more debuging

Comment: echoing result gives this output.

{"cod":"200","message":0.5425,"city":{"id":"7701342","name":"Dhaka","coord":{"lon":90.3996,"lat":23.7132},"country":"Bangladesh","population":0},"cnt":1,"list":[{"dt":1419310800,"temp":{"day":18.86,"min":13.24,"max":18.86,"night":13.24,"eve":18.86,"morn":18.86},"pressure":1026.27,"humidity":79,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01n"}],"speed":1.25,"deg":294,"clouds":0}]}

Comment: I've tryed that string in http://jsonlint.com/ and it says that it's incorrect. Also, it's diferent to the string of your url

Comment: I was trying on jsonlint.com using this url 

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=dhaka%2Cbangladesh&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=3

They are saying its a valid json data

Comment: I don't know why the strings are diferents but they are. One has 489 characters more than the other

Comment: Thanks Serpes. In one url i was calling only 1 dataset and in other i was calling 3 dataset, Thats why. Problem solved.